# I want to call a procedure inside another procedure

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

```
create or replace PROCEDURE pro1 (
        P_ID NUMBER,
        P_USID NUMBER,
        P_MSG OUT VARCHAR2 )
    AS 
      V_EXCEP       EXCEPTION;
      V_ERR_MSG     VARCHAR2(1000); 
      CURSOR C1
      IS
      SELECT * FROM temp1
      WHERE temp1.id=P_ID;      
    TYPE TYP1
    IS
      TABLE OF C1%ROWTYPE;
      V_TYP1 TYP1 := TYP1();
      V_TYP2 TYP1 := TYP1();
      V_TYP3 TYP1 := TYP1();  
    BEGIN        
    BEGIN
      OPEN C1;
      LOOP
        FETCH C1 BULK COLLECT INTO V_TYP1 LIMIT 10000;
        EXIT
      WHEN V_TYP1.COUNT = 0;  
       BEGIN
        FORALL i IN 1..V_TYP1.COUNT         
        INSERT  
        INTO temp2(`enter code here`
        c1,
        c2,
        c3,
        c4
        )
        VALUES
        (
         1,
        '2',
        -- want to call second procedure here e.g., (sp_pro2),
         1
        );
         EXCEPTION
          WHEN OTHERS THEN
          v_err_msg :=  'ERROR WHILE INSERTING INTO  temp2';
            RAISE v_excep;
         END;
      END LOOP;
      CLOSE C1;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
      v_err_msg :=  'ERROR WHILE INSERTING INTO  temp2';
        RAISE v_excep;
    END;
    END;
```

Comment: _-- want to call second procedure here e.g., (sp_pro2)_  I think you want a [function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/plsql-subprograms.html#GUID-13BEBBEC-02D4-48E8-A059-DFEAC4751A3B) there and not a procedure. What's stopping you? You don't know the syntax? Refer to Oracle documentation, specifically _PL/SQL Language Reference_ for the Oracle database version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Calling a procedure at your comment is not possible because there is no return value from a procedure. You have to use a function.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5009.htm